# How to work with JLabel?

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

[image]

Hi i am trying to make java desktop application where i am using `JLabel` I wrote some test on `JLabel` I want to set text from  the top and I am using multiple line in `JLabel` I want to set different different color for every line.

Here is my code:

```
JLabel label = new JLabel("<html>Case &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Item&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; CaseNum<br>Party1<br>Party2</html>");
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Do you want to achieve this manually or thru a program?

Comment: i want to do thru program

Comment: Try storing the text in a separate `String`, then analyze and format it.

Comment: You have enough rep to post an image. Please do so, showing what desired output you want.

Comment: can u send little  program

Comment: Why not use several `JLabel` and an appropriate `LayoutManager`?

Comment: @SébastienLeCallonnec Nice touch! It'll be _easier_.

Comment: Actually, isn't your example exactly a `JTable`?

Comment: my major task is to set jlabel text on the top of the jlabel

Comment: @SébastienLeCallonnec  +1 for `JTable`.  Using the Nimbus PLAF the default is too alternate row colors.  E.G. as seen in this [image of a table using Nimbus](http://i.stack.imgur.com/0okxX.png).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using the html tables for new lines as below,

```
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

/**
 * @author JayaPrasad
 * 
 */
public class SwingHtml {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JLabel label = new JLabel(
                "<html>Case &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Item&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; CaseNum<table><tr><font color=blue>Party1</font></tr><tr><font color=red>Party2</font></tr></table></html>");
        frame.add(label);
        frame.setSize(new Dimension(250, 130));
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: text is not displaying from top and this is my major problem

Comment: @user3456343 I am not getting?? Can you post the output u need? I am not actually getting from 'text is not displaying from top'!! You mean you have some space between "Case" and the "Party 1"?

Comment: i posted image  as a desired out put u can check

Comment: i mean  casenum    item     court should start from top there should not be any spaces from the top

Comment: *"should start from top there should not be any spaces from the top"*  I think the OP means `frame.pack()` instead of `frame.setSize(new Dimension(250, 130));` to fix that problem..

Answer (score 2):

Use a `JTable` for this, rendered the same way as in the Nimbus PLAF.

[image]

Comment: why i can not jlabel?

Comment: Would it look as good (*or* be as functional) as that seen in the image in my answer?  I doubt it.

Comment: i have devloped almost code and if i will try to change i my code it could be hedic  so i want to use jlabel

Comment: @user3456343 you are using tabular data, so it seems fitting to use a table, doesn't it?

Comment: i just want to start casenum  item   court from top of jlabel  i dont want spaces from the top  of the jlabel thats it

Comment: my client has been fixed this gui and he dont want any change  so i can not make any change so please help me

Comment: *"i just want"*  So there is never going to be more data in that label?  I had assumed it was tabular data.  As an side, The behavior of a table **is to put everything at the top** (with no space).

Comment: *"my client has been fixed this gui and he dont want any change"*  He wants it to stay broken?  Sorry, can't help with that..

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
 <html><p><font color="green">line 1</font></p><br /><p><font color="red">line2</font></p></html>
```

if you want to change the line 1 text colour and add a new line 2 with a new colour